# Deleting all CK Editor instances

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

online solutions didn't work.

I'm working on an Application where I dynamically generate HTML and I need to fire CK editor on them but I get the error of 'this editor has already been attached' when length exceeds 1

this seems what I want but I try to get this done by this solution online but that didn't work

```
for(name in CKEDITOR.instances)
{
    CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy(true);
}
```

how can I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check if the instance exists for that element and then perform the action:

```js
if (CKEDITOR.instances['textarea_name']) {
  CKEDITOR.instances['textarea_name'].destroy();
}
CKEDITOR.replace('textarea_name');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't know the names of the editable content (paragraphs in my case) I just need to dynamically delete all the instances

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil That's what I have mentioned. You don't need to delete all. Just check if the element has the instance and then destroy. You will need to loop on all the instances

Answer (score 1):

Walk through the `CKEDITOR.instances` and destroy each of them.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.forEach(key) {
   if (CKEDITOR.instances.hasOwnProperty(key) {
       CKEDITOR.instances[key].destroy();
   })
}
```